# How to install last stable version of Ruby with RVM without root privileges?

Tags: command-line, bash, ruby

I'm creating a bash script to install automatically the last stable version of ruby without root privileges. This is what I have so far:

```
#Install GPG Keys
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import

#Install RVM
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --ignore-dotfiles
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile

#Set environment
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

#Install Ruby
rvm install $RUBY_VERSION
```

I need to find the last stable Ruby version to set `RUBY_VERSION` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the last stable version is always the last file with a filename like `ruby-2.5.1.tar.gz` on https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/, you can extract the version number with:

```bsh
curl -s https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ | sed -nr '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/.*ruby-([0-9.]+).tar.gz.*/\1/p'
```

This approach uses [`curl` [image: Install curl]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/curl) to retrieve the file list and [GNU `sed` [image: Install sed]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sed) to cut out the version number as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297063/6164712). You could also use `grep` with [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead, it even may be slightly faster:

```bsh
curl -s https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ | grep -oP '(?<=ruby-)\d\.\d\.\d(?=.tar.gz)' | tail -1
```

Just add a line setting the `RUBY_VERSION` variable to your script:

```bsh
#Get version number of latest stable Ruby version
RUBY_VERSION=$(curl -s https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ | sed -nr '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/.*ruby-([0-9.]+).tar.gz.*/\1/p')

#Install Ruby
rvm install $RUBY_VERSION
```

#### Example run

```bsh
$ curl -s https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ | sed -nr '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/.*ruby-([0-9.]+).tar.gz.*/\1/p'
2.5.1
$ curl -s https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ | grep -oP '(?<=ruby-)\d\.\d\.\d(?=.tar.gz)' | tail -1
2.5.1
```